# iOS UIPageViewController page control getting out of sync

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

Whenever I swipe the page controller and tap the `UIPageControl` at the bottom in the opposite direction of the swipe at the same time, the page that is currently being displayed and the page number in the pageControl will be out of sync.

Has anyone ever had this weird issue and solved it?

Let me know if you need any additional info.

Comment: Wow, great find. I just verified something similar in one of my apps. Swiping on the page control changes the page indicator but not the underlying page.

Answer (score 0):

Just checked out the docs for `UIPageControl`. I never realized this myself, but you can use page controls for input:

> When a user taps a page control to move to the next or previous page, 
>   the control sends the UIControlEventValueChanged event for handling by 
>   the delegate. The delegate can then evaluate the currentPage property 
>   to determine the page to display. The page control advances only one 
>   page in either direction.

My suggestion would be to either disable the page control or update your app to respond to input on it. Setting `userInteractionEnabled` to `false` on my page control resolved the problem for me.

Comment: Hi @Greg, I tried setting my page control's userInteractionEnabled false.But in my case it behaved same when I started scrolling fast in to and fro direction.I tried returning the current index in  presentationIndexForPageViewController and again the same result. I also tried updating the page in - (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed. And it worked smoothly but somewhere in between its behaving the same.

Comment: Not sure what the problem might be. Here's my controller: https://github.com/gk-brown/MarkupKit/blob/master/MarkupKitExamples/PageViewController.swift  The `currentPage` property is added by a category on `UIScrollView`: https://github.com/gk-brown/MarkupKit/blob/master/MarkupKit/UIScrollView%2BMarkup.m