# How to track index of UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I want to create a general UIPageViewController to use in my project. Here is what it like.

[image: UIPickerViewController]

When scroll or tap on the number in the titleView, the page view should scroll to the according index, and the according number in title should be highlight. But there is a bug when quickly scroll to next page and scroll back, the title view's status is incorrect.

For example, if I'm in page 2, then scroll to page 3 and quickly scroll back, now I'm in page2 but the button of 3 is highlight.

Here is the key codes:

```
//Delegaete

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, willTransitionTo pendingViewControllers: [UIViewController]) {
    willShowPageIndex = getIndex(ofController: pendingViewControllers[0])
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
    guard completed else { return }
    // track the index
    selectedPage = willShowPageIndex
}

fileprivate var selectedPage = 0 {
    didSet {
         //Change the button's font color, and move the underline
        changeShowStatus(oldPage: oldValue, newPage: selectedPage)
    }
}
```

It seems like when quickly scroll page view, the `pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, willTransitionTo pendingViewControllers: [UIViewController])`  didn't invoke. Maybe posting notification in datasource controller's viewWillAppear could avoid this problem, but I don't want this cause this PageViewController should be general.

Any one have better solution?

Comment: Despite that It's Objective-C, I've created a similar controller https://github.com/hons82/THSegmentedPager ther you should find the needed callbacks to implement

Comment: How do you scroll back, through tapping or by scrolling/panning/swiping? See this question, if you mix both navigation types, because those might mess up the current page index: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406833/uipageviewcontroller-setviewcontrollers-uipagecontrol-not-showing-right-current?rq=1 & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36500447/ios-uipageviewcontroller-page-control-getting-out-of-sync

Comment: @hons thanks for help. And I have saw your code, use scroll view can solve my problem, but is there any simple way to solve this?   Hard code to calculate the point may be not the best way to solve the problem. By the way, sorry for my english.

Comment: @Lepidopteron Through swiping the page. The question could be more simpler: how to get the correct index when quickly swiping scroll the page. It seems like PageViewController API don't working correct. When fast scrolling, the pageViewController(willTransitionTo) may not be invoked.